# find the equation of line given normal direction and normal distance

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find the equation of a line given only the normal direction and normal distance to this line?

[image: where a is the normal direction and d is the normal distance]

where a is the normal direction, d is the normal distance and O is the origin.

Comment: Hint: the point at the end of 'd' segment is $(d\sin a, d\cos a)$ and the angle between the line and the OX axis is $a+\frac\pi 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $(\cos a, \sin a)$ is normal to the line, which passes through the point $(x_0,y_0)=(d\cos a, d\sin a)$, hence the equation of the line is
$$\color{red}{x\cos a+y \sin a}=x_0\cos a+y_0 \sin a=d(\cos^2a+\sin^2a)\color{red}{=d}.$$

Comment: now i'm trying to plot this line, is this correct: $f(x)=\frac{(d-x \cos a )}{\sin a}$?

Comment: As the equation of a function, it's correct. However, to plot rhe line,  it's easier  to get the $x$ and $y$-intercepts directly from the cartesian equation, which are respectively  $\dfrac d{\cos a}$ and $\dfrac d{\sin a}$.

Comment: You mean $d \cos a$ and $d \sin a$? but anyway, I don't get it. how this will help me to draw the line? I need to place this function inside a `for` loop.

Comment: No, I mean the fractions. It helps drawing the line, at least by hand, since these are the abscissa of the $x$-intercept and the ordinate of the $y$-intercept, so you have two ‘canonical’ points on the line.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can see that the vector $\overrightarrow{OB}= (d\cos a , d\sin a )$ is orthogonal to the line. If you consider other point P(x, y) in the line, then: $$\overrightarrow{OP}\cdot \overrightarrow{OB} = (x, y)\cdot (d\cos a, d\sin a) = xd \cos a + yd\sin a = d|\overrightarrow{OP}|\cos\theta.$$

Observe than $\cos \theta$ is always equal to $d/|\overrightarrow{OP}|$. Therefore it is: 
$$ xd \cos a + yd\sin  a = d|\overrightarrow{OP}|\cos\theta = d^2.$$
That is to say, that the equation of the line is:
$$x \cos a + y\sin a = d.$$

Good Luck!

Comment: now i'm trying to plot this line, is this correct: $f(x)=\frac{(d-x \cos a )}{\sin a}$?

Answer (score 0):

In $x-y$ plane the equation of the line is given by

$$ax+by=d$$

beeing the normal $n=(a,b)$ such that $|n|=1$, indeed by dot product between $OP$ and $n$ for any point $P=(x,y)$ on the line we have

$$(x,y)\cdot (a,b)=ax+by=|OP|\cos \theta=d$$